# "cannot find symbol " error in oop pig game

Tags: java, oop, class, symbols

I was doing oop pig game. In which I encounter an error: "`cannot find symbol        class name"`. Can you please help me finding it.

```
 public class Player 
 {
    protected String name;
    Scorekeeper sk;
    // sk =  new ScoreKeeper();

    public Player(String name)
    {
      this.name = name;
      //Scorekeeper sk = new ScoreKeeper();
      sk = new ScoreKeeper();
    }

    public Player(){  }

    public int getScore()
    {
       return sk.getGameTotal;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
       return name;
    }

    public int incScore(int rollValue)
    {
       sk.addToRoundTotal(rollValue);
       return sk.getRoundTotal;
    }

    public int setScore()
    {
      return sk.resetRoundTable();
    }
  }
```

This is the class where I create an object for the class `ScoreKeeper` and the other class is

```
public class ScoreKeeper {

    int gametotal = 0;
    int roundtotal = 0;

    public ScoreKeeper() 
    {
        //gametotal = 0;
        //roundtotal = 0;
    }

    public void addToGameTotal() {
        gametotal += roundtotal;
        resetRoundTotal();
    }

    public void addToRoundTotal(int value) {
        roundtotal += value;
    }

    public void resetRoundTotal() {
        roundtotal = 0;
    }

    public int getRoundTotal() {
        return roundtotal;
    }

    public int getGameTotal() {
        return gametotal;
    }
  }
```

when I try compiling the class

```
        Player.java:5: cannot find symbol
        symbol  : class Scorekeeper
        location: class Player
        Scorekeeper sk;
        ^
      1 error
```

Comment: If `Scorekeeper` class is in different package then import the class.

Comment: Addition to Martin Weber, if you are using eclipse or another IDE, try to use `Ctrl+Space` as much as you can. This command shows you possible variables/classes etc. Also depending on how much of the word you write, sometimes, auto-complete or auto-correct what you write. With that your mistakes like that will decrease dramatically.

Answer (score 5):

In your Player-class you wrote:

```
Scorekeeper sk;
```

The "k" needs to be upper case like this:

```
ScoreKeeper sk;
```

Java is a case-sensitive language